# Understanding proof of Poincaré recurrence theorem in Measure and Category (Oxtoby)

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, baire-category

In Oxtoby's book he states thrm 17.1 (Poincaré's recurrence theorem), and deduces it from a generalized form (thrm 17.2). To my understanding, he deduces it in two parts- first he proves that every $x\in G\subset X$ is recurrent, except a nullset, and afterwards he proves the same argument except a set of first category.

These two parts are understandable, but theorem 17.1 states that this is true except a set **of first category and measure zero** at the same time. I struggle to see why this should be the case after proving each part separately.

Comment: There is a certain set, call it *N*, that is the set of non-recurrent points. The first proof shows that *N* has Lebesgue measure zero and the second proof shows that *N* is first category. It follows that *N* is both Lebesgue measure zero and first category.